# Why is my floated image being moved out of my div when I float other div's?

Tags: html, image, css

Why is the floated image being moved next to a paragraph inside of a **div** move outside of that **div** when I float other **div** elements?

For example, I have a **div class** with a paragraph in it and that when I float the image inside of that class it wraps around it the way I want?

```
.container {
margin:0px auto;
width: 1400px;
background-image: url(back.png);
padding-top:10px;
height: 2000px;
}


.main {
background-color: #f7f4f4;
margin-right: 600px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #705656;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid red;}

.green {
border: 2px solid blue;
width: 400px;
margin-right: 40px;
background-color: #8bed8f;
float: right;}


.aside {
background-color: #f47575;
width: 400px;
margin-right: 40px;
border-radius: 4px;
float: right;
clear: right;}

.trac input[type=button] {
background-color: #9b878b;
font: weight: bold;
font-size:15px;
color: white;
border-radius: 6px;
border: none;
padding: 20px 10px;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 5px;}

.tmac { 
  float: left; }
```

Comment: Please share your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understanded your problem (the question you asked is a bit messy), you have to consider that floating HTML elements wraps to the closest position relative container.

If you want to stick a float to a specific container, you just have to add to the CSS class of that container the rule `position: relative`

Comment: so the image is floating inside the container when i put it in between the the other two classes that are floated in my HTML, but even when i apply the relative position attribute to the image it just sticks out of the container @diego

Comment: @CheckLife be sure that your container is bigger enough to keep the image inside. You can get this using a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after all floating elements. (I recommend put that style in a css class like "clear" and it will be cleaner, `<div class="clear"></div>`).

Also ensure the image doesn't have padding or margin affecting its position

Comment: yeah so the thing is i didnt float the container itself, but when i did thats when it works, as well as adding the attribute "overflow: auto". i just want to understand how to do it with out applying those.

Comment: You can always use other positioning methods, like position: absolute (still sticks into the the closest container with position relative) instead of floating. Float can be very usefull but in large webpages can be a pain when something doesnt fit where you want. If you use position absolute, the container will always ignore the child's size and try to be smallest as possible (0,0 if not defined some height or width, or its has no element with position static/relative).

Comment: yeah youre right, i fully understand how position works, i just really like the complexity that comes with floating hahaha. Hey is it possible i can ask you a question about my javaScript as well?

Comment: go for it, create a new question and if you send me the link i'll have a look and response if I can help ;)

Comment: but how would you be able to look at the code if i sent you the link when the files are on my computer? @diego

Comment: @CheckLife i though you want to ask some questions like this one, so this is why i asked you to post them. Reviewing your code is something that requires more time and right now I cant :S Single and specific questions are faster and simpliest to response

Comment: gotcha and sorry!